# How to post data through ASIHTTPRequest in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, asihttprequest

How to post form field data (name, email,phonenumber,score) through ASIHTTPRequest. I am using json webservices.

Comment: Tried the well written documentation of ASIHTTPRequest?

Comment: thanks for replying me @Till.. I ma using ASIHTTPRequest instead of NSMutableURLRequest but it gives error like   ASIHTTPRequest is undeclared.

Comment: NSURL *urlString = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.nieuwe-dag.nl/mobile_be/public/?action=saveScore"];
 ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:urlString];

Comment: [requestWithURL:urlString];
 [request setPostValue:@"asit" forKey:@"name"];
 [request setPostValue:@"m.kulkarni@easternenterprise.com" forKey:@"email"];

Comment: [request setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"businessType"];
 [request setPostValue:@"30" forKey:@"score"];
 [request startSynchronous];

Comment: These i am doing.. please let me know

Comment: error is: /Users/rahulmakode/Desktop/DepartmentalStoreAdmin-4 2/Classes/LoginViewController.h:61:0 /Users/rahulmakode/Desktop/DepartmentalStoreAdmin-4 2/Classes/LoginViewController.h:61: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'ASIFormDataRequest'

Answer (score 1):

Try this , assign variable in your header class

ASIFormDataRequest *requestASI;

in your .m file

```
 -(void)startASIRequest {

NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://your url"];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:strUrl];

[self setRequestASI:[ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url]];

[requestASI setDelegate:self];

[requestASI setRequestMethod:@"POST"];

[requestASI setPostValue:@"1" forKey:@"name"];

 [requestASI setDidFailSelector:@selector(uploadFailed:)];

[requestASI setDidFinishSelector:@selector(uploadFinished:)];

[requestASI startAsynchronous];


   - (void)uploadFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest {

NSLog(@"registerFinished %@",[theRequest responseString]);

  }

  - (void)uploadFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)theRequest {

NSLog(@"registerFailed %@", [theRequest error]);
```

}

Comment: `%d` on a NSString? I think you mean `%@`.

Comment: it will give 9 error when in create ASIFormDataRequest *requestASI; in .h file

Comment: error is :/Users/rahulmakode/Desktop/DepartmentalStoreAdmin-4 2/Classes/LoginViewController.h:61:0 /Users/rahulmakode/Desktop/DepartmentalStoreAdmin-4 2/Classes/LoginViewController.h:61: error: expected specifier-qualifier-list before 'ASIFormDataRequest'

Comment: Try this tutorial http://www.building43.com/blogs/2010/05/28/reading-rss-feeds-on-iphoneipad-with-asihttprequest-and-cocoa-rss/                   http://www.xprogress.com/post-46-building-custom-forms-in-your-iphone-app-using-imessages-asihttprequest-and-json-framework/